# How to use Django with Tornado web sockets?

Tags: django, websocket, tornado

I am trying to figure out a way to connect Django with Tornado web sockets. There will be a list of products rendered on an html page.  As soon as new product is added through django admin panel, the html page will be updated without reload.

Comment: You're better off using something like [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to add websocket support directly into Django. I've used Tornado and Django together. It's a little complicated setup. You need a Messaging Queue (like Redis) to communicate between Django and Tornado. For smaller and early stage projects, `django-channels` should be the way to go.

Comment: I was actually able to connect django with tornado web sockets. Going to post my answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to mix frame works more than two. And making SPA (website without reloading), should not use Django. It's too much to build SPA. Backend as only Tornado, frontend as React with create-react-app, it's so easy to learn and simple.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using Django as a backend for SPA. I've used it for a few projects and it works fine. Even Instagram uses Django for backend and React for frontend.

Comment: Eww, in your way, people will continue to pile of tightly coupled mogules... Technical debt... cycle perl?

Comment: But I pursued source codes of Django, was quite interesting!! Metaprogramming is best!

Comment: How does using Django specifically cause technical debt, but using Tornado doesn't?

Comment: Relative problem. Django brings huge technical debt with tightly decoupled MVC framework, but Tornado only REST API and Websocket. If you want to use Django as useful DB, I will continue saying to use ORM like SQLAlchemy. MVC framework and SPA are quite incompatible.

Comment: Django is definitely not tightly coupled. You can use third party ORM, templating systems, etc with it. You don't have to use Django's all MVC features, you can use it just for the REST API backend for the SPA. Thousands of people do it. Tornado should be preferred for real-time, or network IO intensive applications. Other than that, there's not much advantage of Tornado over Django.

Comment: OK, OK, we proficients taste differ whether to use Django. But for beginners, Django is too much. They might not become able to tell of which feature Django or Python. Various features sometimes confuse us. In education, it's important that how programming works is primitive. I think so.